# Ubuntu 20.04.03 Livepatch issue

Tags: security, canonical, canonical-livepatch

I am experiencing issues with Livepatch and I am getting this error:

> Canonical Livepatch has experienced an internal error. Please refer to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Livepatch#CommonIssues for further information.

I tried `sudo canonical-livepatch refresh`, but it did not work.
I tried `sudo ua attach`, and it worked, but after reboot the error is back.

The following didn't work

```
sudo canonical-livepatch disable
sudo canonical-livepatch enable "token"
```

Do you have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Similar/Same q https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376275/canonical-livepatch-has-experienced-an-internal-error-on-start-up That one as the most details in the question regarding the error.

Comment: Linux 5.11.0-40-generic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Canonical Livepatch has experienced an internal error, on start up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376275/canonical-livepatch-has-experienced-an-internal-error-on-start-up)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo systemctl restart snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service
```