# canonical-Livepath error which I can not find it

Tags: kernel, canonical-livepatch

I received an error by following
Canonical Livepatch has experienced an internal error. Please refer to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Livepatch#CommonIssues for further information.
How can to solve it ?

Comment: See my question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376275/canonical-livepatch-has-experienced-an-internal-error-on-start-up/1376756#1376756  - particularly update 4, it may well be fixed for you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Canonical Livepatch has experienced an internal error, on start up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376275/canonical-livepatch-has-experienced-an-internal-error-on-start-up)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Canonical Livepatch internal error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142602/canonical-livepatch-internal-error)